# Facing issue, barcode font not applied on gegnerated PDF

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, iis-7.5, barcode, crystal-reports-2008

I am generating PDF using crystal report. Crystal report containing barcode font - free 3 of 9.

This is web application - ASP.NET 4.5.

ItS all working fine in DEV machine.

When hosted on iIS 7.5 then, barcode is not applied on generated PDF file.

have alreaddy installed font on IIS as well.

please guide what to do for resolving this issue.

Is it something permission issue for font ? any one has idea on this.

thank YOUu

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "have alreaddy installed font on IIS as well" -- in what way do (you think) you have installed a font in IIS?

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment so I will have to do it through here. Do you have a specific width of your barcode field? Is it possible that, since free 3 of 9 barcode font is a very long stretched out font that it could be extending longer than the width of your field therefore it's not showing up? Also, How are you receiving the barcode font data, are you pulling the data from another field and converting it to a barcode? If this is the case, check to make sure you are actually able to retrieve the data that you want for your barcode, it may not be getting it at all outside of your DEV machine.